# Solve an equation with binary rotation and xor

Tags: systems-of-equations, binary, binary-operations, python

i'm having fun solving equations in Python but i'm stuck somewhere...
I simplified the system $$\begin{cases}
 4 = rol(rol(a, 2) \oplus rol(a \oplus b, 2) \oplus c, 3) = rol(b, 5) \oplus rol(c, 3)\\
 6 = rol(c, 7) \oplus rol(b, 6)
\end{cases}$$ to obtain $$\begin{cases}
b = ror(4, 5) \oplus ror(c, 2)\\
c = ror(6, 7) \oplus ror(b, 1)
\end{cases}$$ and then $$b = ror(4, 5) \oplus ror(6, 9) \oplus ror(b, 3) = ror(4, 5) \oplus ror(6, 1) \oplus ror(b, 3) = 140 \oplus ror(b, 3)$$ where $\oplus$ is a xor operation, $ror$ is a 8bit rotation to the right and $rol$ is a 8bit rotation to the left.

Does anyone knows how to solve this kind of equation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it's pretty simple.
Let's do this on 4 bits, and call each bit by a letter.$$ b = 6 \oplus ror(b, 3)$$ means $$ABCD \oplus 0110 = BCDA$$
You then just need to xor bit by bit $b$ and $6$. Because $xor$ inverts if the second part is a $1$ and do nothing if $0$, we can say that : $$\begin{cases}
A = B\\
B = \bar C\\
C = \bar D\\
D = A
\end{cases}$$
There is two solutions to this :$$\begin{cases}
A = 0\\
B = 0\\
C = 1\\
D = 0
\end{cases}$$
or $$\begin{cases}
A = 1\\
B = 1\\
C = 0\\
D = 1
\end{cases}$$
So the equation $b = 6 \oplus ror(b, 3)$ has two solutions : $$b = \{2, 13\}$$
We can observe that there will always be an even number of solutions which are binary opposite two by two.